# Creating a pivot chart without displaying the column by which the pivot table is sorted

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-charts

I am trying to display a number of total sales for each worker on a pivot chart. I need to sort the data in the table according to total sales however I don't want to display the total sales on the pivot chart. Is there a way to achieve this? 
[Total sales from highest to lowest (pivot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp30A.jpg)

Basically, I want to preserve the order shown in a picture attached above without displaying the total sales on the chart. 
Like this: [Total sales from highest to lowest (normal chart)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jnR6.jpg)

By the way, I know how to achieve this without the pivot table, it's just that I am  currently learning about them.

Comment: Remove the total sales field from the pivot table.

Comment: @BigBen legendd